# Write a exact exception to log file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, sh

I have one **shell script** file and command line are:

```
mkdir test
```

When i execute shell script file ,test folder is created.
Same shell script file executed second time and it throws error "Already test folder is exist".

**Need**:

In this case i need to create a log file and write the exact exception in log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like below:-

```
log_buffer=$(mkdir test 2>&1)
#you can put any command under $()
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "$log_buffer" >> log.txt
fi
```

First what is `2>&1` here? Normally if `mkdir test` fails the output will be redirected to `standard error` by O/S. In that case it will not stored in `log_buffer` variable. To store the output we need to redirect standard error to `standard ouput` and `2>&1` is exactly doing the same

Now what is `$?` here. Once you execute a shell command the command's return status stored in `$?` variable. If a command executes successful in Unix the value stored in `$?` is `0` and if failed it will be some other number/value based on exit status of that program. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I need dynamic exception instead of hard code value.Its Possible?

Comment: @Mano, yes that is possible. I have modified my answer

Comment: @Mano, Just try with my example and let me know whether working or not.

Comment: @Abhijit-Awesome .Its working perfect and also detailed explanation.

Comment: @Abhijit-One more doubt here.This is single step,so handled this way.when i am using more command line,then how to handle it?

Comment: -Thanku so much

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to create a log file:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

The, you can do:

```
try:
    # your logic goes here
except Exception e:
    logging.exception("Full traceback of your error")
```

It will put all the traceback in the log file so you will be able to explore the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this to log the exact error to a log file

```
#!/bin/sh

temp_file=$(mktemp)

mkdir test 2>$temp_file
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $(cat $temp_file) >> log.txt
        rm -f $temp_file
fi
```

`mktemp` command creates a temporary file in /tmp directory. /tmp directory files are not disk files and they don't exist across reboots.